# C++ compiler differences: Putting a function into std::pair

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

I've recently encountered code that tried to put a function (not a function pointer) into a `std::pair`, and which was accepted by GCC, but not by Clang. This lead me to investigating what is "correct" here in terms of the C++ (17) standard. Consider this:

```cpp
void foo(int) {}

// (1) Not allowed in GCC, Clang or MSVC
std::pair<decltype(foo), decltype(foo)> myFirstPair;

// (2) Compiles in GCC, fails in Clang and MSVC
auto myPair = std::pair{foo, foo};

// (3) Compiles in GCC, Clang and MSVC
auto myOtherPair = std::make_pair(foo, foo);
```

(also [here at the Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/ahvbYnW9d))

Obviously you can't have a function type as a member (which would be the consequence of deducing one of `T1` or `T2` of `std::pair<T1, T2>` to the function type `void ()(int)`), but function pointers are fine. Indeed that seems to be what's happening in the cases where compilation succeeds: For `(3)`, both Clang and GCC deduce the type `std::pair<void (*)(int), void (*)(int)>` for `myOtherPair`. For `(2)`, GCC also deduces `std::pair<void (*)(int), void (*)(int)>` for `myPair`.

I assume what's happening here is a function-to-pointer conversion as per `[conv.func]` of the standard:

> 7.3 Function-to-pointer conversion [conv.func]
>
> An lvalue of function type T can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”. The result is a pointer to the function.

Clang, GCC and MSVC all seem to apply that conversion to the arguments of `std::make_pair`, and only GCC seems to apply that conversion to the arguments of `std::pair`'s constructor.

Since the standard only specifies that a conversion *can* happen (and does not even say in which cases this can happen), are all three compilers correct? Is this just something that's not specified by the standard?

Comment: Number 2 compiles fine in MSVC 17.3.5 (C++ latest). 
Number 1 if you write decltype(&foo) (address of foo) instead (sure, its the same then as the others).  
So, I cannot answer the question, but I think that a conversion to a function pointer must be done if otherwise the compilation fails. Old compiler versions were just buggy.
I cannot imagine that those kind of language things are "implementation defined".

Comment: _does not even say in which cases this can happen_ It does, in relevant places.

Comment: Oh, and Number 2 also compiles fine in MSVC 17.3.5 (C++17). So, it is not something special about C++17.

Comment: @TeaAgeSolutions: Interesting, neither (1) nor (2) work with MSVC 19.x (which is what the Compiler Explorer has available): https://godbolt.org/z/ezPMPK6z8 And sure, if I manually use `&foo` to go from function type to pointer-to-function type, everything just works. My question was rather: why do some compilers automatically do the function-to-pointer conversion, and some don't?

Comment: We have CTAD `template<class T1, class T2>pair(T1, T2) -> pair<T1, T2>;` and the implicit deduction guides (in particular `pair( const T1& x, const T2& y )`) but the conditionally `explicit` make that the signature is not that simple :-/

Comment: In addition gcc/msvc c++17 passes, but not in c++20 [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/947cxK4hx)

Comment: Some clarification / info for the MSVC versions: On godbold the latest version of MSVC is VisualStudio 2017 (as far as I can see). Don't know why they name it 19.x there, it should be 15.x instead. I tested with VisualStudio 2022, which is 17.x with C++latest (which is C++20 + x) as well as C++17. With that number 2 compiles. That makes me believe that older MSVC versions (e.g. on godbold) are buggy and Number 2 should compile on standard conformant compilers. Well, at least it is a hint for it.

Comment: @Lukas Barth: I think its a bug of older compiler versions. At least the MSVC versions in use give a hint towards this direction.

Comment: @TeaAgeSolutions the version on godbolt is correct, it is the version of the compiler, specified by Microsoft. For example 19.32.31332 maps to vs2022.

Comment: Fabian Keßler: Ah, thanks, sure, there was the third number to specify the used version. That makes everything very confusing. At least since the numbers are so closed to each other: 17 VS 19. Ok, but this is offtopic.

Comment: Interestingly, I wonder why auto myPair = std::pair{foo, foo}; does not result in std::pair<decltype(foo)&, decltype(foo)&> as the type (reference to function). That conversion looks more natural for me.

Comment: @TeaAgeSolutions: Template argument deduction decays arrays and functions if the parameter type is not a reference.  One could use a deduction guide to force the issue, but there’s not much reason here (you can’t assign through a function reference anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have boiled this down to a bug in Clang. [This answer is also available as a bug against Clang here.](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/58353)

Consider this "minimal" example that I condensed from GCC's STL implementation of `std::pair`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename _T1>
struct _PCC
{
    template <typename _U1>
    static constexpr bool ConstructibleFrom()
    {
        return std::is_constructible<_T1, const _U1&>::value;
        
    }
};

template<class T1>
struct MyContainer 
{
    T1 t1;

    using _PCCP = _PCC<T1>;
    template<class U1 = T1, typename
           std::enable_if<_PCCP::template
               ConstructibleFrom<U1>(),
                         bool>::type=true>
    constexpr MyContainer(const T1& newT1) : t1(newT1) {}    
};

template<typename T1> MyContainer(T1) -> MyContainer<T1>;


void someFunc() {};

int main() 
{
    auto c = MyContainer(someFunc);
}
```

What *should* happen here (I think) is that the constructor of MyContainer is not taken for CTAD. Taking the constructor for CTAD would lead to `T1` being deduced as `void()`, because `T1` is taken as a const reference in the constructor, which prevents function-to-pointer decay when deducing the template parameter for the constructor. But, if `T1` is deduced as `void()`, the `std::enable_if` disables the constructor - so it sholud not be taken for deduction.

The deduction guide below remains, and since `T1` is taken by value there, function-to-pointer decay happens and `T1` is deduced as `void(*)()`. With `T1` deduced as `void(*)()`, `MyContainer` should be fine, since a function pointer can of course be a member.

However, Clang reports this error:

```
<source>:17:8: error: data member instantiated with function type 'void ()'
    T1 t1;
       ^
<source>:21:24: note: in instantiation of template class 'MyContainer<void ()>' requested here
               std::enable_if<_PCCP::template
                              ^
<source>:24:15: note: while substituting prior template arguments into non-type template parameter [with T1 = void (), U1 = void ()]
    constexpr MyContainer(const T1& newT1) : t1(newT1) {}    
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:34:14: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template '<deduction guide for MyContainer>' [with T1 = void (), U1 = (no value), $2 = (no value)]
    auto c = MyContainer(someFunc);
             ^
1 error generated.
```

I assume that this error arises because Clang tries to instantiate `MyContainer<void()>` **during CTAD**, more precisely while checking if the `std::enable_if` is satisfied or not. The locations reported in the error point to that, and: If you remove the using declaration from the class and instead write the constructor like this, the error goes away:

```
    template<class U1 = T1, typename
           std::enable_if<_PCC<T1>::template
               ConstructibleFrom<U1>(),
                         bool>::type=true>
    constexpr MyContainer(const T1& newT1) : t1(newT1) {}
```

Note that this is the same constructor as above, I just manually replaced `_PCCP` with `_PCC<T1>` and removed the `using`.
I assume that Clang somehow needs to instantiate the class (which is impossible with `T1 = void()`) for accessing the using, which is a member of the class.